# Offline Map not populate in OSMdroid from sdcard folder of Android

Tags: android, openstreetmap, android-mapview, osmdroid

I've created a offline map OSMDroid zip file from MOBAC tool and i loaded that into /sdcard/osmdroid/Mapnik.zip in device inside that zip folder there is a folder named as "Mapnik" and this is called as in code. After that inside my android code i tried to fetch that as in offline it doesn't show the tiles and i shared my code too please help me on this.

```
map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("Mapnik", 0, 18, 256, ".png", new String[] {
            "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
            "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
            "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
            "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/"}));
```

Comment: what version of osmdroid?

Comment: Hi, am using "com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.4" package for OSM

Comment: call Configuration.getInstance().getOsmdroidBasePath(), what does that return? because that's where osmdroid is expecting your offline zips to be

Comment: i received following message "OsmDroid: SqlCache - Tile doesn't exist: Mapnik/10/505/353"